# Opening Lotus Notes inside a VB.NET form

Tags: vb.net, lotus-notes, ui-automation, setparent

I've been reading a lot here for almost 5 years already but it's my first post here.

I'm currently working on a VB.NET Project in which I need to have Lotus Notes opened inside a Window Form. I tried using SetParent functionality as I've seen here

http://xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=272163.

It worked for me but the problem is, when a window on my Lotus Notes client has been closed, the whole client will close. When I try to reopen mail, it will display an error of insufficient memory or it will not respond at all.

Image shows Lotus Notes opened inside a VB.NET form

[image: Lotus Notes opened inside a VB.NET form]

I tried increasing heap size values on the registry as stated here but the problem still persist.

http://forum.sysinternals.com/insufficient-memory_topic17945.html

Image shows Lotus Notes doesn't open when I click button1

[image: Lotus Notes doesn't open when I click button1]

I also doubt that Insufficient Memory error is correct because when I checked on task manager the memory usage is not that high.

http://i61.tinypic.com/33jtyxe.png

Any comments and solutions are very welcome.

TIA.

Ross

Comment: Lotus Notes is not a simple program. There are actually two primary executables, notes.exe and nlnotes.exe, and a few others that could be running as well. There is a lot of shared memory involved. My guess is that running it inside another application's window is not a good idea.  Notes is an OLE server, which means that you can embed it and automate it using API calls.  Perhaps if you tell us why you are trying to run it inside your window, what you expect users to do and what you expect to happen, people here can suggest differet ways of getting it done.

Comment: Thanks Richard. These are also my sentiments. Our management wants a system that provides all the common programs an employee needs, like e-mail, office tools, browser, etc. At first my approach was to make it browser based, and use iNotes as the e-mail program, it succeeded, but the management turned it down as it would require all employees to use iNotes, rendering our domino server for Lotus Notes  useless. (we have diff server for Notes and iNotes)

Comment: About the primary executables, yes, I tried calling the two. notes.exe is not an option since it opens a splash screen before calling the actual client, thus, the splash screen is the one being docked on the window and not the client. So I opted to call nlnotes.exe which is the workspace only.

Comment: Unfortunately, I suspect that might be the source of your problem. Only IBM could answer this for sure, but I think Notes.exe may be repsonsible for cleaning up shared memory. The only thing I can think of is after you terminate nlnotes.exe, you could try running notes.exe giving it long enough to clean up (if it can) and then send it the windows event telling it to quit. (It's been too long... I don't remember my Windows event names.)

Comment: Thanks Richard, I had convinced the management yesterday that we would  activate iNotes in one of our alternate domino servers. So yes, I might not have the solution to this issue, but my problem is now solved. We will use iNotes.

Comment: Good choice.  And good job getting management to change their minds! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to do this on our end. We just created a web based application instead and used iNotes for the mail program.